# How to limit the width of the Child DIV and Parent DIV simultaneously and dynamically

Tags: html

I am using the below HTML code. Below is what I am trying to achieve:
I want to parent DIV to take the width of the 'Longest' width of its child DIV.
If you look at the below HTML code segment#1, it works fine but if you look at HTML code segment #2, you will see that the "Test Title" border did not change its DIV width as per the DIV width of its longest child DIV. Please provide any pointers. Thanks.

```
<!-- HTML code segment#1 --> 
<html>
<body>

<div style="font-family:Arial; fontsize:11px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;padding:1px;position:absolute;width:auto;" >

<span tyle="padding:1px,7px,1px,7px; background- color:Blue;color:White;position:fixed;height:25px;" >
 <span style="padding:1px,7px,1px,7px;height:25px; middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle;">

Test Title

</span>

</span>

<div style="margin-top:3px;" >

<p style="padding:2px,1px,2px,1px; margin:0px;">Testing Text1</p>

<p style="padding:2px,1px,2px,1px; margin:0px;">Testing Text2 which is Long</p>         </div>  
 </div>
</body>
</html>


<!-- HTML code segment#2 --> 
<html>
<body>

<div style="font-family:Arial; fontsize:11px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;padding:1px;position:absolute;width:auto;" >

<span tyle="padding:1px,7px,1px,7px; background- color:Blue;color:White;position:fixed;height:25px;" >
 <span style="padding:1px,7px,1px,7px;height:25px; middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle;">

Test Title

</span>

</span>

<div style="margin-top:3px;" >

<p style="padding:2px,1px,2px,1px; margin:0px;">Testing Text1</p>

<p style="padding:2px,1px,2px,1px; margin:0px;">Testing Text2 which is Longggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>         </div>  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you seeing the issue in? I have tested your HTML "segements" in Firefox 3.5.8 and it works fine.

Comment: I think you're going to have to use something like javascript to calculate the width of the child and then have the browser change the width of the parent.  Unless you have something in the child that's a fixed width (like an image) there's not really any way to do what you're wanting server-side.  

I know that doesn't give you an answer (I'm no good at JS, but it helps refine your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Set the max width of the parent div to the min width of the longest child div.